# Some special characters are not appearing in Text Field of Android

Tags: android, settext

In my app user is asked to input text. But some special characters are not appearing

User input :  test{ "@","\" }
Actual result : test{"",""}

How can I fix this ?    is there anything special required with text.setText() code ?

Comment: What `inputType` are you using?

Comment: have you used layout.xml?? if yes then put that code here..

Comment: I am using inputType : TYPE_CLASS_TEXT                                     and I am creating text field in code not in layout.

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344493/android-how-to-set-acceptable-numbers-and-characters-in-edittext

Answer (score 1):

use text watcher and Input Filter interface implemetation

Comment: Actually I want those special characters to appear . How can I do it?

Comment: use the ascii values 
@ -- &#64;
\ --&#92;

http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: How can I use Ascii values ??