# how can i prevent to take input onkeypress anything other than alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

My application is in Arabic and English. Its a hybrid application (html/css/jquery/android).
we have one text field in one page and it should take input only alphanumeric (i.e., abc123).
i want to prevent input other than alphanumeric. ( some customer are using Arabic keyboard and they enter something else from Arabic keyboard.
and here it showing question marks (?) in database.)

So I have to prevent input other than alphanumeric.
Please suggest me how can i prevent to take input as arebic or anything other than alphanumeric. Thanks in advance.

this is my code...

```js
function isAlphaNumeric(e){ 
 var k;
 document.all ? k=e.keycode : k=e.which;
 return((k>47 && k<58)||(k>64 && k<91)||(k>96 && k<123)||k==0);
 }
```

```html
<input type="text"  OnKeypress="javascript:return isAlphaNumeric(event,this.value);" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the XML:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "
```

Comment: Do you have any idea in javascript/jquey ? as mentioned in my code sample. thanks albert for answering.

Comment: you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434076/best-way-to-alphanumeric-check-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Since `jquery` is tagged I am giving this solution. I think you can use regular expression for this like the one below:

```js
 $('#text1').keypress(function (e) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }
    
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1">
```

Comment: Hi guru, thanks for your comment, your code is working fine in computer's browser but its not working in mobile hybrid app. Thats why I am using keycode on keypress like this. (k>47 && k<58)||(k>64 && k<91)||(k>96 && k<123)||k==0); and its  working partially fine... like we cant input special character but it takes rupees symbol and also it takes arabic letter.

Comment: @GaurabKumar.. You can try **[this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10344887/2065039)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow both caps and small

```
<EditText
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:digits="qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM0123456789"/>
```