# How to restrict input type in DialogAlert to alphanumeric?

Tags: android, android-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validations in android/eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928946/validations-in-android-eclipse)

I've seen this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082859/how-to-restrict-textview-to-allow-only-alpha-numeric-characters-in-android) but the top answer only works for `TextView`s defined in the manifest file, which is not my case. I'm using a `DialogAlert` object to ask for a String, which can only be alphanumeric.

**[UPDATE]**

```
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivityS.this);
    setUserIdAlertDialog.setView(input);
    setUserIdAlertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yesLabel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            Utils.sendStringIntent(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.ACTION_ACTIVITY_NEW_ID), "ACTIVITY", value, getString(R.string.INTENT_EXTRA_NEW_USERNAME));
        }
    });



    setUserIdAlertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.noLabel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                          }
                                    });
    setUserIdAlertDialog.show();
```

Comment: post your code for dialog also

Comment: its not only for TextView it will work with EditText too http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929070/1012284

Comment: That only works when defining through the manifest file I think. I can't get it to work programatically.

Comment: are you asking how to restrict input type of an edittext programatically?

Comment: I know I can check each char or something like that, I also know there are a few input types in android (none of which are alphanumerical only), so yes, keeping those two exceptions in mind, I am asking that