# Android prevent other language except English in Input with an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an android app where the user has to enter his name by using Input with an AlertDialog, and I am wondering if its possible to prevent the user from entering other languages except English.

[image]

here is the code that I use:

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
  Editable value = input.getText();
  // Do something with value!
  }
});

alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    // Canceled.
  }
});

alert.show();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this attribute , with edittext

> ```
>  android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
> ```

with java code

> ```
>  editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));
> ```

Comment: I think he is trying to prevent other languages except english. Your example just allows the letters, but this has nothing to do with language

Comment: no it will not work with alert you better integrate with edit text post you full xml and java code

Comment: final EditText userName = new EditText(context);
  
  userName.android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Comment: @Sainath Patwary karnateI fixed it, I used it with EditText but it gives me error

Comment: @ Sainath Patwary karnate when I tried the code on my phone the keyboard only view numbers ?

Comment: add this line before setKeyListener  editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                            return ""; 
                    } 
            } 
            return null; 
    } 
  }; 

 edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file you need to put this,

`android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "`

also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6082975/1367450).